# android FileInputStream EOF

Tags: java, android, exception

I am creating a new File object like so:

```
keystoreFile = new File(getDir("sslDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "CAKeyStore.jks")
```

Later, I try to use the the file for an input stream like so:

```
 BufferedInputStream bufstream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile));
            Log.d(TAG, "Available? " + bufstream.available());
            sslKeystore.load(bufstream , KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
```

and in logcat I get an EOF Exception, and "available" bytes shown is zero

```
 Available? 0
07-09 18:00:13.090  11229-11229/de.blinkt.openvpn W/System.err﹕ java.io.EOFException
07-09 18:00:13.090  11229-11229/de.blinkt.openvpn W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
07-09 18:00:13.090  11229-11229/de.blinkt.openvpn W/System.err﹕ at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:103)
07-09 18:00:13.090  11229-11229/de.blinkt.openvpn W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:799)
07-09 18:00:13.100  11229-11229/de.blinkt.openvpn W/System.err﹕ at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:589)
```

However, if I clear my apps data, and try this again, I don't get the problem.

Is there something wrong with the way I am creating the file, such that when the app is re-loaded I get this EOF exception?

Edit:

The method where the file is actually created is within this function:

```
private void saveKeystore() {
    try {
        sslKeystore.store(new FileOutputStream(keystoreFile), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unable to save keystore");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you writing the file? could you be missing `flush()` / `close()`?

Comment: I'm having trouble following the sequence of events.  Could you provide more details (maybe step-by-step) about your interaction with the file?  When do you created it?  When do you write it?  When do you close it?  When do you reopen it?  When do you get the error?

Comment: new File(filePath); does not create a file. Show relevant code please.

Comment: Edited to clear up I meant big F file, and now have added the method where the Keystore.store() function is called. The saveKeystore() function is definitely called before any attempt to access using the InputStream is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the FileOutputStream yourself. The KeyStore.store() won't do that for you. Ditto the FileInputStream and load(). See the examples in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html).